# what is a way i could summon a creature in a game with certain rules of magic

Tags: magic, video-games

In a game I'm working on, magic is a force that can turn things into similar things (air into fire, lead into gold, air into colder air, etc) it can also hide people or slow time for the user and can be tied to a weapon such as a sword or staff. Later on, it can connect two points in space but only with the power of a magic gem. My question is how exactly a character could summon a demon or a soul to make undead monsters or guards.

Comment: alright so i dont really think this fits here, maybe add some more detail? in the end its your magic system

Comment: Since you made up the other stuff, you could make up something additional to do the demon / undead thing you want.  Maybe a "gem of souls" to be a higher level item similar to your gem of darkness.

Comment: "can turn things into similar things (air into fire, air into colder air,)". I think something is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with the information given (which isn't much):

> Magic can turn things into similar things

- If its for combat, perhaps you could transform a smaller companion creature into a greater threat rather than summoning? A companion bird into a griffin, cat into a tiger, lizard into a wyvern, or similar.
- Your summoners could carry miniature carvings of their intended summon targets and transform them into the genuine article.
- If you intend to summon demons, a summoner could use a corpse, offering, or some other kind of taboo article to be transformed into a demon.

> It can connect two points in space

- Your summoners could pull their summon targets through a gap in spacetime from wherever they may be.
- Your summoners could store their tamed creatures in a pocket of hyperdimensional spacetime.
- If your creatures are especially fantastical, your summoners could summon them from some celestial plane.
- Your character could connect a summoning portal to the underworld from whence he calls forth a demon.

At the end of the day, there's not much information to go on, but these are a few options that fit the criteria listed.